# Restricting the location from which WAS deploys the EAR

Tags: websphere, websphere-6.1

We have a Websphere Application server 6.1 running in a Linux machine. Many team members have admin access to the server. Often, incorrect EARs have been deployed due to manual error. We want to create a common shared location where the development team places the EAR. The deployment people must deploy the EAR only from that shared location.

Is there any way to enforce this in WAS 6.1?

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always

1. Remove them access to WAS (WAS administrative account username/password)
2. Create a [wsadmin script](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/txml_callappinstall.html) for each EAR installation. The script installs only specific file from specific path.
3. Create shell script that runs the wsadmin script from previous step, and provides that authentication
4. Use standard POSIX file access rights so that the developers can run the scripts, but not see the passwords & other information from inside them.

This accomplishes what you require, but requires some scripting.